# Using a Kibana view query from application

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I used the following filter and then searched for query string using Lucene to get the view that I was looking for.

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "eventSource": {
        "query": "ec2.amazonaws.com",
        "type": "phrase"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I do not want to return event names those start with the word describe or get. Rest of the event names from ec2 event source should be returned.

> !(eventName.keyword: Describe* OR  eventName.keyword:
> Get* )

The question is how to combine these 2 search requests into one?
I need to use that query from my application.

---

Update:

The Inspect menu of Kibana Discover tab generates this query. I am just trying to rewrite query_string part with usual match or match_phrase using boolean OR clause.

```
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "!(eventName.keyword: Describe* OR  eventName.keyword: Get* )",
            "analyze_wildcard": true
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "eventSource": {
              "query": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "format": "strict_date_optional_time",
              "gte": "2020-07-09T08:39:15.947Z",
              "lte": "2020-07-24T08:39:15.947Z"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [],
      "should": [],
      "must_not": []
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily use the [boolean query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)'s must_not clause to exclude the documents which you don't want in your search result and you can add as many as `must_not` as you want, it's fairly easy to do and can be done in a single query.

Please refer the example in the same link to get more info. Created sample in my local to show your the correct query, Please note instead of wildcard I am using the [prefix query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html) which is better and server your use-case.

**Create index mapping**

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "eventName": {
                "type": "keyword"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Index sample doc**

```
{
  "eventName" : "Describe the events"
}

{
  "eventName" : "the Describe events"
}

{
  "eventName" : "Get the event"
}

{
  "eventName" : "event Get"
}
```

**Now search query to get only 2 and 3rd doc according to your req**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "prefix": {
            "eventName": "Desc"
          }
        },
         {
          "prefix": {
            "eventName": "Get"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search result**

```
  "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "ngramkey",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.0,
        "_source": {
          "eventName": "the Describe events"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "ngramkey",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": 0.0,
        "_source": {
          "eventName": "event Get"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by the user "Opster Elasticsearch Ninja", I have merged must not boolean query like this...

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": [
              {
                "prefix": {
                  "eventName.keyword": "Desc"
                }
              },
              {
                "prefix": {
                  "eventName.keyword": "Get"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "eventSource": {
              "query": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "format": "strict_date_optional_time",
              "gte": "2020-07-09T08:39:15.947Z",
              "lte": "2020-07-24T08:39:15.947Z"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [],
      "should": [],
      "must_not": []
    }
  }
}
```